# how to write helpfile for powershell snapin

Tags: powershell, pssnapin

I have developed my custom powershell snapin. I wanted to write help for that. Is anyone aware about any tool?

I have already tried ps cmdlet help editor from codeplex (https://pscmdlethelpeditor.codeplex.com/releases/view/573966), but that is not working for me. This tool is able to load from only module 
(module class). When I try to load a snapin (module class), then it throws following error "C**annot bind argument to parameter 'name' because it is an empty string**"

Please let me know in case anyone is aware about any other tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a strong reason to support V1, you should prefer creating a module.  Most snapins work just fine as a module and installation is simpler.

That said, the tool you found is the best free tool I know of - I've used it successfully but it had some small issues.  Maybe you can report a bug or better, fix the bug for yourself.

Other options:

An interesting approach - write a script to generate your ps1xml (way easier than writing ps1xml directly): https://github.com/nightroman/Helps

Here is a promising non-free tool: http://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_helpwriter